# Authorize.net AIM refund transaction error 3.2.33

Tags: php, parameters, authorize.net, authorize.net-aim

According to authorize.net pdf instructions I use the AIM parameters:

"x_login"       => $AimLoginID,

"x_tran_key"        => $AimTransKey,

"x_version"     => "3.1",

"x_delim_data"      => "TRUE",

"x_delim_char"      => "|",

"x_relay_response"  => "FALSE",

"x_type"        => $Type,

"x_trans_id"        => $TransID,

"x_amount"      => $Amount,

"x_card_num"        => $CCLast4,

"x_invoice_num"     => $invoicenumber

where

x_tran_key is the original transaction ID as given to my from authorize.net

type = CREDIT as I want to refund

x_amount equals the exact amount I previously charged on the credit card

x_card_num is filled with the last 4 digits from the credit card.

x_invoice_num has my invoice number

the message I get back gives me an error.
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 33
    [3] => Recurring Billing is required.

this does not make any sense as it is not a recurring billing?

at the beginning I tried it without the invoice number, but the retunred errorcode informed me that I need to give them also that. I also tried to give the parameter x_exp_date as '' (i saw a suggestion for this online) but it didn't work, had the same message.

Any idea or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to cancel the transaction before settlement is occurring? If so, you may want to perform a `Void` instead of a `Credit`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check `x_recurring_billing` - perhaps it is enabled as "required".

You need to access your Merchant Interface. Check if this field is set as Required. 
Just change the FIELD value to NOT REQUIRED.

See more detailed problem explaination here http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Receiving-Response-3-2-33-Recurring-Billing-is-required/td-p/718